# How do return a path variable in a batch file?

Tags: batch, batch-file, path

How can you return a path variable in a batch file? For some reason this code alway returns blank for me.

```
@ECHO OFF
set recentPath = %cd%
echo recentPath is : %recentPath%
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right.

The problem is that you add spaces in your set command, which commandprompt is taking quite literally.

```
set recentPath = %cd%
```

The above command (as copied from your question) does the following:

It sets `recentPath_` to `_%cd%`

Notice how I added a _ (replaced it because the space was not that noticable) after the recentPath, and before %cd%. Yes, if you `echo %recentPath %` while you are in `C:\`, you'll get  `C:\` (notice the added spaces here too).

The correct commands therefor are:

```
@ECHO OFF
set recentPath=%cd%
echo recentPath is : %recentPath%
pause
```